# How to understand which libapache2-mod-php am I using now?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, php

Listing packages

```
# apt list libapache2-mod-php*
Listing... Done
libapache2-mod-php5/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libapache2-mod-php5.6/now 5.6.40-5+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
libapache2-mod-php5filter/trusty-updates,trusty-security 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29 amd64
```

Asking infos to  apache2  [removed useless infos]

```
# apache2ctl -M
Loaded Modules:

 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
```

I am not able to estabilish if I am using php5 o php5.6

Comment: Create a `phpinfo()` file and check that. Also *please update your server*, Ubuntu 14.04 reached EOL in 2019.

Comment: ...or read your apache config and upgrade your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to determine the PHP version.

Here are a few methods:

###### 1. Create a PHP file `phpinfo.php` and run it to display all information.

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

###### 2. Display the available modules:

`grep -iR "php" /etc/apache2/`

###### 3. Display loaded modules:

`cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*.load`

###### 4. Display your PHP version:

`php -v`

###### 5. `grep` for the `php.ini` file

`php -i | grep "php.ini"`

###### 6. `grep` for `libphp*.so` in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules`

`ls /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ | grep "php"`

###### 7. `grep` for Version

`php -i | grep "PHP Version"`

###### 8. `grep` for `pdo`

`php -i | grep "pdo"`

###### 9. `ls` in `/usr/bin/`

`ls /usr/bin/php*`

###### 10. `grep` in `/sbin/apache2ctl` for available configuration directives

`/sbin/apache2ctl -L | grep "php"`